# Embedding a pdf into a view from Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a simple Controller Action that returns a pdf as a FileContentResult. I would like to embed the pdf onto a new window and add some other html elements like buttons to the view. I've tried statically inserting an object tag and then dynamically setting the data attribute that points to my controller action url. This does nothing at all. I've also tried using PDFObject to basically do the same thing, but that does not work either (although strangely fiddler says that my action method cannot be found, although I just used it previously on same page). I suspect that since nothing is interacting with the object tags they never trigger the action in the url. How can I point to a Rendered pdf file in an mvc action that takes dynamically generated parameters? Also right now I get no exceptions.

```
// My controller 
    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult GetReportFile(string pReportType, string pK2ID, DateTime pPeriodRun) 
    { 
        return new FileContentResult(DataModel.KrisReportDataModelProp.GetReportFile(pReportType, pK2ID, DateTime.MinValue), "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "test.pdf" }; 
    } 

// My javascript 
var pdfReportResult = new PDFObject({ 
                            url: '../../KrisReport/GetReportFile?pReportType=' + lReportTypeSubmissionQuerySelector.val() + '&pK2ID=' + lK2ID + '&pPeriodRun=' + lPeriodRun 
                        }).embed('reportPlaceHolder');
```

Comment: After multiple attempts at figuring this out. I resorted to using an iframe instead of an object tag. This is not "the answer" to the question, but for those that were having similar issues and who's application allows the use of an iframe, it is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently I faced an issue when I had to submit a form, validate it, and if it was valid, present an option to the user to download a pdf file. Please note, that downloading a pdf file was optional. A user needed to click on a button "Download Pdf", which was not available before initial form was validated. This sounds like something similar to your problem.
I achieved this by doing following:

**View Model:**

```cs
public class PatientModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public byte[] PdfByteArray { get; set; }
}
```

**Actions on the Controller:**

```cs
// Action to display initial form
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreatePatient()
{
    PatientModel model = new PatientModel();
    return View(model);
}

// Action to post patient
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePatient(PatientModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // whatever logic to save new patient
        mPatient.Save(model);

        // whatever logic to generate pdf byte[]. I have a helper for this.
        string html = "[some html based on which a pdf will be generated]"
        byte[] pdf = PDFHelper.GeneratePDFFromContents(html);
        model.PdfByteArray = pdf;
    }

    return View(model);
}

// action to download PDF file given byte[]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PdfFromByteArray(byte[] pdfByteArray)
{
    return File(pdfByteArray, "application/pdf", "MyHistory.pdf");
}
```

**View:**

```
@model PatientModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    First Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
    Last Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)
    @html.ValidationSummary()
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("PdfFromByteArray", "[Controller Name]"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PdfByteArray)
        <input type="submit" value="Download File" />
    }
}
```

Here if initial form is valid I embed byte array of pdf into a view as a hidden input. If user requests pdf to be downloaded (submits second form with that hidden input), it calls another action that generates pdf from byte[] and returns it.